# Rails: How to use select method to fetch items with certain value in a row of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new with ruby on rails and have been stuck no a problem for a while. I'm using rails 4.2.3

Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :tag, dependent: :destroy

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
```

I used following code to fetch user's tag (as an example)

```
user = User.find(1)
tags = user.tag
```

The row (hash for tags) fetched from Tag Model looks like this:

```
 => #<Tag id: 1, user_id: 1, summer_programs: true, scholarships: false, stem: false, humanities: false, computer_science: false, traveling: false, community_service: false, research: false, internships: true, arts: false, created_at: "2015-08-11 17:15:04", updated_at: "2015-08-13 21:37:35">
```

What I want now is: Pick up items with value true. In this case, they should look like:

```
{summer_programs: true, internships: true}
```

I wrote follwoing codes:

```
truetags = tags.select{|key, value| value == true}
```

But this returns me error:

```
NoMethodError: private method `select' called for #<Tag:0x007fcfd6f563d0>
```

Any thoughts? Thank You.

Comment: Do you want user has_many :tags, (not has_one)?

Comment: @Swards  I'm using has_one because I want each user has only one set of tags. I built a model for the set of tags called Tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because tags is an array of active records not a hash. Try

```
truetags = tags.select{|tag| tag.summer_programs && tag.internships}.
```

I think you want to map over all the records and only select the fields which are true. You can use the attributes method.

```
truetags = tags.flat_map { |tag|tag.attributes.select {|k,v| [k,v] if v==true}}
```

Not sure if there's an active record way to do this, but worth exploring if you have a lot of records.

Comment: Thanks for tips. flat_map returns undefined function. I used following codes to fix the problem: truetags = tags.attributes.select{|key, value| value==true}

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the tags where summer programs and internships are true, try this.

```
truetags = Tags.where(summer_programs: true, internships: true)
```

If you want those tags for each user

```
truetags = user.tags.where(summer_programs: true, internships: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this - add it to User

```
# user.rb

def self.in(*args)
  results = joins(:tag)
  args.each do |arg|
    results = results.where(:tags => {arg => true})
  end
  return results
end
```

Then request users like

```
User.in(:summer_programs, :internships)
```

You could take this approach and do more with it, error check, etc.